# MUI styled component shouldForwardProp

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

```
const MyThemeComponent = styled('div', {
  // Configure which props should be forwarded on DOM
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) =>
    prop !== 'color' && prop !== 'variant' && prop !== 'sx',
  name: 'MyThemeComponent',
  slot: 'Root',
  // We are specifying here how the styleOverrides are being applied based on props
  overridesResolver: (props, styles) => [
    styles.root,
    props.color === 'primary' && styles.primary,
    props.color === 'secondary' && styles.secondary,
  ],
})(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: 'aliceblue',
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
}));
```

Anyone can explain what shouldForwardProp does?
Actually i'm struggling to understand this piece of code

```
shouldForwardProp: (prop) =>
    prop !== 'color' && prop !== 'variant' && prop !== 'sx',
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4):

In a nutshell it's asking *"Do you want the `color`, `variant`, and `sx` props that you set on instances of `<MyThemeComponent />` to also be set on the underlying `div` element that you're styling?"*.

In this case, the answer is probably *"no"* because those three props are not valid attributes on a `div`. Since a `styled` component "forwards" any props that are passed to it to its underlying element/component by default, the `shouldForwardProps` function lets you filter the ones out that you don't want passed. In this case the `shouldForwardProps` functions says "if the props passed to me are ***NOT*** `color`, `variant`, or `sx`, then ("yes") put them as attributes on the `div`."

In this example image, you can see that I commented out your `prop !== color` line and the `color` props was passed to the underlying `div`, as an attribute, while `variant` and `sx` are not being passed:

[image]