# Additional props for styled components in TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

According to https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/typescript/#complications-with-the-component-prop

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const CustomButton = styled(Button)({
  // your custom styles go here
}) as typeof Button;
```

we use `as typeof Button` to fix some TypeScript limitations

When we need to have additional prop, lets say `foo` and `bar`, we should do

```
const CustomButton = styled(Button)<{foo:string,bar:string}>({
  // your custom styles go here
}) as typeof Button;
```

but we get error

```
Type error: Conversion of type 'StyledComponent<{ children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses> | undefined; color?: OverridableStringUnion<"inherit" | "primary" | "secondary" | "success" | "error" | "info" | "warning", 
ButtonPropsColorOverrides> | undefined; ... 9 more ...; variant?: OverridableStringUnion<...> | undefined; } & ... 4 mor...' to type 'ExtendButtonBase<ButtonTypeMap<{}, "button">>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficient
ly overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'StyledComponent<{ children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses> | undefined; color?: OverridableStringUnion<"inherit" | "primary" | "secondary" | "success" | "error" | "info" | "warning", ButtonPropsColorOverride
s> | undefined; ... 9 more ...; variant?: OverridableStringUnion<...> | undefined; } & ... 4 mor...' is not comparable to type '(props: { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses> | undefined; col
or?: OverridableStringUnion<"inherit" | "primary" | "secondary" | "success" | "error" | "info" | "warning", ButtonPropsColorOverrides> | undefined; ... 9 more ...; variant?: OverridableStringUnion<...> | undefined; }...'.        
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type '{ href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses> | undefined; color?: OverridableStringUnion<"inherit" | "primary" | "secondary" | "success" | "error" | "info" | "warning", ButtonPropsColor
Overrides> | undefined; ... 9 more ...; variant?: OverridableStringUnion<...> | undefined; } & Omit<...' is not comparable to type '{ children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses> | undefined; color?: OverridableStringUn
ion<"inherit" | "primary" | "secondary" | "success" | "error" | "info" | "warning", ButtonPropsColorOverrides> | undefined; ... 9 more ...; variant?: OverridableStringUnion<...> | undefined; } & ... 4 more ... & { ...; }'.       
        Type '{ href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses> | undefined; color?: OverridableStringUnion<"inherit" | "primary" | "secondary" | "success" | "error" | "info" | "warning", ButtonPropsCol
orOverrides> | undefined; ... 9 more ...; variant?: OverridableStringUnion<...> | undefined; } & Omit<...' is missing the following properties from type '{ foo: string; bar: string; }': foo, bar
```

if we remove `as typeof Button` is works but we lost type annotation. What is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what Typescript limitations you're encountering that you need to [assert the type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (`as Button`), but your first case could be handled by adding the `ButtonProps` type:

```
import Button, { ButtonProps } from "@mui/material/Button";

// Notice ButtonProps
const CustomButton = styled(Button)<ButtonProps>({
  // your custom styles go here
});
```

And to extend the props for your second case, you can use an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) to add whatever you need:

```
import Button, { ButtonProps } from "@mui/material/Button";

const CustomButtonWithCustomProp = styled(Button)<
  ButtonProps & { foo: string; bar: string }
>({
  // your custom styles go here
});

<CustomButtonWithCustomProp foo="baz" bar="none" variant="contained">
```

**Working CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-intersection-3p5ls9?file=/demo.tsx

### Extra Credit

Don't forget your [`shouldForwardProps` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74750742/mui-styled-component-shouldforwardprop) if you don't want your new props forwarded to the DOM.

```
const CustomButtonWithCustomPropsFiltered = styled(Button, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "foo" && prop !== "bar"
})<ButtonProps & { foo: string; bar: string }>({
  // your custom styles go here
});
```